# Infinity loop login after install JDK-9

Tags: java, login-screen, bashrc, jdk, environment

I'm not a Linux superuser. However I decided to install official JDK-9 so I done those steps:

```
wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" \
http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/9+181/jdk-9_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz \
-O jdk-9_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
```

Move to /opt/

```
sudo mv jdk-9_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /opt/
```

unzip:

```
cd /opt/
sudo tar -xzf jdk-9_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
```

update-alternatives:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk-9/bin/java 1000
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk-9/bin/javac 1000
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javadoc javadoc /opt/jdk-9/bin/javadoc 1000
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javap javap /opt/jdk-9/bin/javap 1000

sudo update-alternatives  --config java
```

I choose [1]

```
0 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java    [Auto]
1 /opt/jdk-9/bin/java                               [manual mode]
2 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java    [manual mode]
```

After that I got this:

```
update-alternatives: using /opt/jdk-9/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode
```

After all steps I still getting jdk 1.8.0 after using

```
java -version
```

So I edited `/etc/environment/`Now it's look like this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-9
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

And I also edit `~/.bashrc` (when I install JDK-8 I added to end of file)

```
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java'
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH
```

After logout I can't login. And of course I getting infinity loop login. I can fix something with **ctrl+alt+F1** console but I don't know what...
I think I spoiled something in `/etc/environment` or `~/.bashrc`

Can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can get in using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, using `nano` editor change:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-9
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

To:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-9
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

Then remove this:

```
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java'
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH
```

To:

```
JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java'
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH
```

The restart the system.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution helped me to fix this problem.
Have a good day!

Comment: Setting `JAVA_HOME` *twice* will do no good. The last assignment will override all earlier assignments.

Comment: Yes I know my aim was to get him in but I will update that